# Where can I find free digital dungeon tiles?

Tags: online-resources, dungeon, tiles, roll20

I'm currently running a D&D 4e campaign on Roll20. I have been drawing the maps in Roll20, but it's a hassle and I'd like to switch to something pre-made. Most of the tiles on Roll20's site aren't free and I don't really like the ones for sale anyway. I also sometimes work in Masterplan, which really works best with tiles.

Where can I get tiles for free? Are there any alternatives to pre-made dungeon tiles for drawing dungeons online?

Comment: Not really, I'm looking for online free resources to build my own maps, such as grids and tiles; however most of the links are to Insider and pay-to-print content.

Comment: Related (lots of answers cover creating/generating dungeon tile style maps): [What tools are available to create custom dungeon maps?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/what-tools-are-available-to-create-custom-dungeon-maps)

Comment: I think I have some links around somewhere... I'll have to try and dig them out when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The awesome **dungeonmorphs** are free in multiple formats! These are old-school in art style but made to match each other perfectly in terms of entrances and exits. I have the dice and the cards and love them. You get 90 of them in PDF, PNG, and dungeonographer (which is also free) formats.

http://www.dungeonmorphs.com/battlemats.shtml

Comment: I've skimmed through them and they look absolutely horrible, sorry :/

Comment: They look actually pretyt good only for dungeon design, it could save me some time! But I'll wait for more answers befor epicking this as the best. mHowever I'll have to see if they're roll20 compatible.

Comment: @Lohoris - Horrible? Really? I think that's pretty harsh, but others obviously disagree. Maybe we have different goals for dungeon tiles?

Answer (score 4):

[MapTool](http://www.rptools.net) long predates Roll20, and while I won't recommend it as *software* (and it appears to no longer be actively developed), there's a large library of tiles (free and otherwise) that have been built up around it, which should all be compatible with Roll20.

Here's a few links to the more active resource sites, taken from the list [here](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=community) (and checked myself).

- The [Dundjinni forums](http://www.dundjinni.com/forums/)
- [RPG Map Share](http://rpgmapshare.com/index.php?q=gallery&g2_itemId=45482?g2_GALLERYSID=)
- The [User Creations](http://forums.rptools.net/viewforum.php?f=8) section of the RPTools forum.

In addition to whole tiles, there's also pieces you can simply assemble into your own rooms - walls, floors, objects, etc.  Poke around and see what you can find.

Comment: Looking at the MapTool Forums I'd say its still actively developed,

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer - I stand semi-corrected.  They might still be actively developing it, but the last released version was a year and a half ago.  There's definitely still active *users*, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of Pyromancers Dungeon Painter. It is free to use software that allows you to use a good variety of tools to make your dungeons. I can usually build a 7 room level in about 30 minutes. Once you are done it is easy to make a JPG file of your dungeon and paste it on Roll20.